# What exactly should be called "projection matrix" in the context of PCA?

Tags: pca, terminology, linear-algebra

At the end of the PCA algorithm one gets a $D\times d$ matrix $U$ such that $z=U^Tx$ (here $x$ is $D$-dimensional and $z$ is $d$ dimensional with $d\leq D$). In multiple sources on the Web I found that $U$ or $U^T$ is named "projection matrix", but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix) it cannot be since $U$ is usually not a square matrix (usually $d<D$). The true orthogonal matrix is $UU^T$, which is also named "projection matrix" across the Web.

Maybe it is correct to say that $U$ or $U^T$ is the **projection matrix** and $UU^T$ is the **orthogonal projection matrix**?

There is not a clear definition or am I missing something? Are there more appropriate names for those matrices in order to not confuse them?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381991. I've just posted an answer there and it sort of answers this question too.

Comment: @user_anon can you be more exact about the statement that say that  U must be a square matrix? Your reference relates to the projection matrix in linear regression which is a different thing. Also how is U not square? PCA is a mapping/projection to spaces of the same dimension. (it is just that you make some columns zero when you reduce the dimensionality)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$U U^T$ is the [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)) operator. I believe calling $z = U^T x$ a projection is an abuse of terminology. It is actually a coordinate transformation, where each value in the new coordinates is computed by a [scalar projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection) onto the principal vectors. $U U^T x$ is the orthogonal projection of the data onto the principal vectors in the original coordinates, and $U^T x$ is the orthogonal projection of the data onto the principal vectors in the new coordinates (principal components).